# JavaScript input arguments separated with space

Tags: javascript

Today I've received couple recruitment tasks from one company. They're pretty specific in those tasks that's why I'm wondering if I'm missing something. I got problem with one. No matter what function should return, I know how to manage but here's how input looks:

X

x1 x2 x3...

So big X is quantity of little x's. For example:

5

1 2 2 2 3

So how should I create a function taking X number of x's that operates on x's? What type should I expect as argument?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: could you please elaborate more about "So big X is quantity of little x's" what do you mean by that?

Comment: It is possible to count function inputs by `arguments.length`. But I'm not sure it is what you want.

Comment: Sure, big X in example is 5 and there are 5 numbers given

Comment: So, if we help you with the task, do we get the job? ;-P It's impossible to answer the question, as it depends on what the task is looking for. I expect it's looking for creativity on your part to answer the question...

Comment: Your goal is to make a function that takes a specific number of arguments? People that make tests like these are out of their minds. This literally proves nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can either directly use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameter)

For arrays, use `myFunc`, `myFunc2` utilizes the rest parameter.

```
// ARRAY AS SINGLE PARAMETER
function myFunc(numbers) {
    for (var i of numbers) {
        console.log(i); // Do whatever you like to do here
    }
}

// REST PARAMETER
function myFunc2 (X, ...xs) {
    console.log(X); // The number of arguments
    for (i of xs) {
        console.log(i); // One argument per iteration
    }
}

var xarr = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3];
var X = xarr.length; // X is 5
console.log(X);

myFunc(xarr); // Passes the numbers as an array to your function.
myFunc2(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // Uses the rest parameter
```

The expected result (in the console using the Array method) would be

```
5 // <- This is X (i.e. the amount of numbers)
1 // <- First number ...
2
2
2
3
```

I hope this is the answer to your question - otherwise please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the rest operator (`...`) like such:

```js
const f = (...args) => `${args.length} items given: ${args.join(', ')}`;

f(1, 2, 3, 5, 6); // 5 items given: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're accepting a number as the required length of parameters being given, you could do something like this:

```
let x = n => (arr) => (arr.length === n) ? arr.toString() : "Invalid Size";
```

```js
let x = n => (arr) => (arr.length === n) ? arr.toString() : "Invalid Size";

let a = x(5)([1,2,3,4]), b = x(5)([1,2,3,4,5]);
console.log(a,b);
```